# Duplicating a composition

Tags: copy, adobe, after-effects

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to paste a `composition` directly into a chosen `bin`? I
   always paste it and have to scroll in the `project viewer` until I
   find it, then drag it to the wanted `bin`.
2. Is there an easy way to "deep copy" a `composition` (meaning, making a copy of the inner `compositions` as well)?

Comment: For the first question, you mean with a script or in the application ?

Answer (score 0):

For the question 2 :

> "deep copy" a composition

If you mean duplicate a composition and its children, even compositions, a script called [True Comp Duplicator](http://aescripts.com/true-comp-duplicator/)  already exists and you can read through the code if you download it. Go see `function tcd_duplicateCompStructure(comp, tcd_depth)` line 738 in `True Comp Duplicator.jsx` and read the code.